# "dvc add -external S3://mybucket/data.csv" is failing with access error even after giving correct remote cache configurations

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-s3, dvc

I'm using dvc and connecting to remote S3 for data track and also setting remote dvc cache in same remote S3.
Following is configure file,

```
[core]
    remote = s3remote
[cache]
    s3 = s3cache
[‘remote “s3remote”’]
    url = S3://dvc-example
    endpointurl = http://localhost:9000/
    access_key_id = user
    secret_access_key = password
    use_ssl = false
[‘remote “s3cache”’]
    url = s3://dvc-example/cache
    endpointurl = http://localhost:9000/
    access_key_id = user
    secret_access_key = password
    use_ssl = false
```

I'm able to push and pull from remote repository to local using s3remote.

But when I try to add external data by configuring cache(s3cache), am getting error.

Both s3cache, s3remote has same credentials, then why is it failing when I add external data in dvc?

Comment: Seems like this is (being) answered in https://discuss.dvc.org/t/dvc-add-external-s3-mybucket-data-csv-is-failing-with-access-error-even-after-giving-correct-remote-cache-configurations/726 .

Comment: Yes, Thanks @JorgeOrpinel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to use the special `remote://` URL format to `add --external` data using existing remote configurations:

```
dvc add --external remote://s3remote/wine-quality.csv
```

wine-quality.csv is in location s3://dvc-example/wine-quality.csv, here **remote://s3remote** is replaced by `url` string in config file.

I got answer after posting question in DVC forum.
[Link to answer](https://discuss.dvc.org/t/dvc-add-external-s3-mybucket-data-csv-is-failing-with-access-error-even-after-giving-correct-remote-cache-configurations/726/5)